# Is there any difference between "go to the city centre" and "go into the city centre"?

Tags: prepositions

Is there any difference between *go to the city centre* and *go into the city centre*? For example:

> I am going to **go to the city centre** tonight.
>
> I am going to **go into the city centre** tonight.

By the way is it idiomatic to just say *to/into the centre*? For example:

> Would you like to go to/into **the centre** tomorrow?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we say "go INTO the centre"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/97179/why-do-we-say-go-into-the-centre)

Answer (score 1):

As you say, "go into the centre" is idiomatic. As a native British English speaker, this is what I am most used to hearing and what I would say myself.

Normally you would say that you go *to* somewhere *specific*; while we go *into* an area.

"Go to the centre" sounds like you are going to the 'dead centre'; that is the precise central point of something. A "city centre" is not necessarily the central point of a place, but is what we call the main business and commercial area of a city. As you are entering an *area* rather than going to a fixed point, it makes sense to say "into".

Comment: I disagree, there is a subtle difference between into and to in terms of the action and in most cases "the city center" is said to be gone "to" not "into".

Comment: @SovereignSun There is a difference, I thought I'd explained that? The difference is idiomatic, you won't necessarily get that from a dictionary.

Comment: I could and I would prefer to know of such a difference in place of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the two sentences demonstrate two differnet approaches.

> to go to

means to go until one sees/meets/experiences someone or something, while

> to go into

rather highlights crossing (kind of) a border/barrier and entering an area.

I would generally use the first option - just in analogy to *to the cinema*, *to the zoo*. And, please, consider the famous supporter of my view: Santa Claus, who always comes (i.e. *goes* - from his point of view) **to** town.

I would use the second option specifically to highlight a zone border or a barrier like in *Don't let us go into the city center. The car park is much more expensive there.*